# Azure DevOps - Query to find work item by branch

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to query in Azure DevOps for retrieve all the work items related to a specific branch.
In this way I can figure out all the work done in the latest few month on that specific branch.
But I don't know if is possible or how to formulate the query to specify the branch. It is possible? If yes, which is the correct field?

[image: ev]

Comment: I think you can't by default, you must to add a new custom field of "branch" and fill it each time.

Comment: @Gioce90 Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

> Query to find work item by branch

For this issue , it is impossible to achieve by default. At present, there are no fields pointing to branches in azure devops, so you cannot query the work items related to a specific branch by specifying field.

As a workaround , agree with Shayki , you can customize a related branch field for the work item in the inherited process and fill it, so that you can retrieve the work item related to a specific branch by specifying the related branch field in the query.

[image]

[image]

In addition , you could also submit your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) site , which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

Comment: Hi, I don't think this suits well to my needs, because in real life a Work Item can be associated to more than one branch. If I understood right, in this way I have to specify a single branch in a field, and do this manually. Awful. And what if I create first the Work Item and than the branch? What to do with old branches and existing work items? 
In my opinion, it would be great if I can query for one or more associated branches to discover which work items are associated with these branches, likewise in the work items' Links > Branches window.

Comment: I think what you want is a good idea! But this is currently not possible.So I post a feature request [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/989386/query-to-find-work-item-by-branch.html) in DC forum. you could vote that suggestion ticket and share your comment there,The product team would provide the updates if they view it.